# How to prevent node js from serving .git folders and all the files under .git

Tags: .htaccess, git, node.js

I know that using .htaccess file can restrict files to be served under .git but how do i acheive the same if i'm using node.js server. I use forever to start/stop the servers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Express, the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11911629

You did not provide enough information on your setup to give a more detailed answer.